# Как на атмега 8 менять вход на выход и обратно в цикле работы

Tags: avr

Пробую написать так, но не работает:

```
if(PIND & (1<<PIND1)){DDRC |=   (1 << PC0);PORTC &= ~ (1 << PC0);}
else {DDRC &= ~ (1 << PC0);PORTC |=   (1 << PC0);}
```

выход как то мерцает не туда не сюда нормальный выход непреврощаеться в протеусе даже а когда сделал на микроконтролере тоже самое кто может помочь?

Надо написать программу с одним любым портом.

Comment: if(PIND & (1<<PIND1)){DDRC |=   (1 << PC0);PORTC &= ~ (1 << PC0);} 
  else {DDRC &= ~ (1 << PC0);PORTC |=   (1 << PC0);}

Comment: Зачем в else **выключается** вывод, а затем производится **запись** в порт?

Comment: мне и надо чтоб при условие порт стал выходом с нулём а если условия нет то вход с подтянутом резистором

Comment: толька я немогу правельно написать

Comment: как менять вход на выход и вход

Comment: у меня все ножки задействованы даже ресет под выход мне не хватает по этому надо использовать не котырые как вход и выход при некоторых условиях

Comment: Гм... С программной стороны вроде всё правильно... По поводу предыдущего вопроса — не обращай внимания... мне показалось, что запись в PINC.

Comment: правельно но неработает

Comment: выход как то мерцает не туда не сюда нормальный выход непреврощаеться в протеусе даже а когда сделал на микроконтролере тоже самое

Comment: что то не правельно я больно то неочень понимаю пробовал по всякому результата нет

Comment: Если проблема не здесь, то она либо в аппаратной части либо где-то ещё в программной.

Comment: Самая банальная ошибка: диод, который используется для мониторинга вывода подтягивает ногу к нулю.

Comment: програмная ошибка наверное что то нетак делаю или нехватает какойто каманды

Comment: не получаеться если бы знал вчём причина сам бы исправил и неспрашивал

Comment: я несилён впрограммирование понадобилось мне вот сделать управлениями двумя электрическими воротами в гараже и автосигнализацией связать чтобы открывала переключала ворота и показывала состояние на брелке

Comment: вроде всё сделал работает неполучаеться в пультах с кнопками привезать светодиоды когда команда включилась на открытия например должен на кнопке загореться светодиот пока ворота недойдут до бесконтакного датчика и команда прервёться ворота остановяться и светодиод должен потухнуть и снова работать как вход с кнопки

Comment: Не надо задавать одинаковые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

нашёл ошибку сам почему порт перемигивал пока программа работает проходило по else других команд порт переводился туда сюда пришлось помудрить и сделать чтоб менялось один раз как то так вышло

```
if(PIND & (1<<PIND0)) 
{T2=1;DDRC |=   (1 << PC2);PORTC &= ~ (1 << PC2);}
if(T2==1){if (!(PIND & (1<<PIND0)))
{T2=0;DDRC &= ~ (1 << PC2);PORTC |=   (1 << PC2);}}
```